# Gensim vector shape changing

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, shapes

i am trying to vectorize a text and classify it by using gensim and tensorflow.keras.

Before the train I have shapes as follows:

```
X_train, y_train (1019471, 100, 1) (1019471, 5) 
X_validate, y_validate (127419, 100, 1) (127419, 5) 
X_test, y_test (127476, 100, 1) (127476, 5)
```

```
    for function in functionSource:
        func_list.append([str(preprocess_text(function))])
    return func_list
```

```
def preprocess_text(sen):
    # Remove punctuations and numbers
    sentence = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', sen)

    # Single character removal
    sentence = re.sub(r"\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+", ' ', sentence)

    # Removing multiple spaces
    sentence = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', sentence)

    return sentence
```

```
    embedding_dim = 100
    model = Word2Vec(func_ist, min_count=1,size= embedding_dim, workers=6, window =3, sg = 1)
```

After the train I have the following shapes:

```
X_train, y_train (1018222, 100, 1) (1019471, 5) 
X_validate, y_validate (127398, 100, 1) (127419, 5) 
X_test, y_test (127461, 100, 1) (127476, 5)
```

**logging for gensim**

```
INFO: 2020-07-20 12:44:54,936 - word2vec.py:1596 - scan_vocab : collected 1018222 word types from a corpus of 1019471 raw words and 1019471 sentences
INFO: 2020-07-20 12:44:54,936 - word2vec.py:1647 - prepare_vocab : Loading a fresh vocabulary
INFO: 2020-07-20 12:44:56,790 - word2vec.py:1671 - prepare_vocab : effective_min_count=1 retains 1018222 unique words (100% of original 1018222, drops 0)
INFO: 2020-07-20 12:44:56,790 - word2vec.py:1677 - prepare_vocab : effective_min_count=1 leaves 1019471 word corpus (100% of original 1019471, drops 0)
INFO: 2020-07-20 12:44:58,912 - word2vec.py:1736 - prepare_vocab : deleting the raw counts dictionary of 1018222 items
INFO: 2020-07-20 12:44:58,930 - word2vec.py:1739 - prepare_vocab : sample=0.001 downsamples 0 most-common words
INFO: 2020-07-20 12:44:58,930 - word2vec.py:1742 - prepare_vocab : downsampling leaves estimated 1019471 word corpus (100.0% of prior 1019471)
INFO: 2020-07-20 12:45:00,543 - base_any2vec.py:1022 - estimate_memory : estimated required memory for 1018222 words and 100 dimensions: 1323688600 bytes
INFO: 2020-07-20 12:45:00,543 - word2vec.py:1888 - reset_weights : resetting layer weights
```

I couldn't understand the part that my dataset losing some of the text, can anyone explain to me the reason why the shape gets smaller?

i am trying to learn about the topic. i would be grateful if anyone can explain it

Comment: The `Word2Vec` model isn't operating on any of your `X_train`, `y_train`, `X_validate`, etc – only on `func_list` that's build from `functionSource` (whose value or example data isn't shown). So all the stuff you've written about X/y data shapes has nothing to do with the `Word2Vec` behavior you're asking about here (& should probably be edited out of the question, perhaps saved for a future question when those variables/data are involved).

Answer (score 0):

From your 1st log line...

```
INFO: 2020-07-20 12:44:54,936 - word2vec.py:1596 - scan_vocab : collected 1018222 word types from a corpus of 1019471 raw words and 1019471 sentences
```

You've provided `Word2Vec` with 1,019,471 sentences, which have among them 1,019,471 words. That's one word per sentence. Is that what you intended? (Probably not; since `Word2Vec` needs multiple words in each other's context-windows, it can't learn anything from 1-word-sentences.)

Assuming that's not what you intended, take a look at a few entries in `func_list` – for example `func_list[:2]` – & see if they're what you intended. Remember, `Word2Vec` expects each text it receives, as one item in its `sentences` argument, to be a list of word-tokens.

Further, the count of only 1,018,222 unique words means that the difference (`1019471 - 1018222`) of 1,249 are 'words' that are repeated. No text is lost; the model only creates vectors for *unique* words. (And also note: `Word2Vec` doesn't itself create vectors for longer texts, just individual words. So if you need vectors for longer texts, you'll need to use some other algorithm, or some way of combining all the text's word-vectors into one vector, such as averaging them all together.)

As a separate observation, `min_count=1` is almost always a bad idea. In real natural-language training data, the rarest words have insufficiently-varied usage examples for good word-vectors to be learned. Retaining them means they get bad vectors – & other surrounding words have a harder time, too, with all that rare-word noise around them.

Why your `X_train` etc change shape is impossible to determine as you've shown no code that operates on them - so whatever is changing *their* shape is happening in steps/code you haven't described. (It looks like you might be reassigning into those variable from the `model`? But per above, the model has vectors per unique word, not per input text.)